# Generate integer value in php

Tags: php

I need to convert the string to following format.

```
1000 -> 0000001000
10000 -> 0000010000
25000 -> 0000025000
```

I tried this way `ceil(str_pad($range_array[0],6 , "0", STR_PAD_LEFT))`

But this works for 1000, but fails for 10,000 .

Is there any function to create it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
printf("%010d", $number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're padding with 6, or using `ceil()`. str_pad takes the total length of the string you want:

```
<?php

foreach (array(1000, 10000, 25000) as $int) {
    echo str_pad($int, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sprintf()` to format the number nicely [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
 $result = sprintf( '%010.0f', $inputNumber );
```

Or better still

```
 $result = sprintf( '%010d', $inputNumber );
```